# Why the kubernetes pvc resize can't work with filesystem?

Tags: kubernetes, resize

I want use the Kubernetes feature of dynamic resize PVC. After I edit the PVC size to a large one, only the PV size has changed, but PVC status still is `FileSystemResizePending`. My Kubernetes version is `1.15.3`, in the normal situation the filesystem will expand automatically. Even if I recreate the pod, the PVC status still is `FileSystemResizePending`, and size not change.

The CSI driver is `aws-ebs-csi-driver`, version is alpha.
Kubernetes version is `1.15.3`.

Feature-gates like this:

```
--feature-gates=ExpandInUsePersistentVolumes=true,CSINodeInfo=true,CSIDriverRegistry=true,CSIBlockVolume=true,VolumeSnapshotDataSource=true,ExpandCSIVolumes=true
```

Create StorageClass file is :

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ebs-sc
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowVolumeExpansion: true
```

PV status:

```
kubectl describe pv pvc-44bbcd26-2d7c-4e42-a426-7803efb6a5e7
Name:              pvc-44bbcd26-2d7c-4e42-a426-7803efb6a5e7
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: ebs.csi.aws.com
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection external-attacher/ebs-csi-aws-com]
StorageClass:      ebs-sc
Status:            Bound
Claim:             default/test
Reclaim Policy:    Delete
Access Modes:      RWO
VolumeMode:        Filesystem
Capacity:          25Gi
Node Affinity:     
  Required Terms:  
    Term 0:        topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone in [ap-southeast-1b]
Message:           
Source:
    Type:              CSI (a Container Storage Interface (CSI) volume source)
    Driver:            ebs.csi.aws.com
    VolumeHandle:      vol-0beb77489a4b06f4c
    ReadOnly:          false
    VolumeAttributes:      storage.kubernetes.io/csiProvisionerIdentity=1568278824948-8081-ebs.csi.aws.com
Events:                <none>
```

PVC status:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
  creationTimestamp: "2019-09-12T09:08:09Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    app: test
  name: test
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "5467113"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/persistentvolumeclaims/test
  uid: 44bbcd26-2d7c-4e42-a426-7803efb6a5e7
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 25Gi
  storageClassName: ebs-sc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: pvc-44bbcd26-2d7c-4e42-a426-7803efb6a5e7
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-09-12T09:10:29Z"
    message: Waiting for user to (re-)start a pod to finish file system resize of
      volume on node.
    status: "True"
    type: FileSystemResizePending
  phase: Bound
```

I expect the PVC size will change to the value which I specified. But the PVC status always keep `FileSystemResizePending`.

Answer (score 5):

Right in your pvc status you can see a reason:

```
message: Waiting for user to (re-)start a pod to finish file system resize of
  volume on node
```

You should restart a pod which use that PV, which will cause a remount of PV and FS will be resized before next mount.

Not all file systems can be resized on-flight, so I think that is just a compatibility behavior. Also, that is more safe anyway.

Comment: I have restarted the pod several times.but no change happened.And the filesystem is ext4.

Comment: Is something updated in a PV condition? Also, try to check kubelet logs on a node where new pod working, there should be something about fs resizing or that PV.

Answer (score 1):

Basically down the line resizefs is resizing the amount of space requested, which may take time according to the size of space requested.

You should not delete the pod since unmounting of volume is not supported when resize is in progress. Gives following error:

```
Output: umount: /var/nutanix/var/lib/kubelet/pods/36862d8a-e0bf-4d0f-bdd3-c897a4ed5ccd/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pvc-acad4f90-9811-4371-9512-3e14ed1cbc64/mount: target is busy.
    (In some cases useful info about processes that use
     the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

Even if pod is deleted and is stuck in terminating state, it will ultimately terminate when resize of filesystem completes and a new pod is created.